# Optimizing service calling While filtering

Tags: android, performance, search, filter

I need to do filter in text change and getting data from API , means on each text change it is calling API.

I just want to know how can I optimism this with minimum no. of API calls. Please suggest me the best way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: if you need it for some list oriented view (`ListView`, `AutoCompleteTextView`) then read `android.widget.Filter` class documentation

Comment: Thank you Sir, for quick replay. But I need to do it with list view and need to call API for data on text change. Please guide me...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830